# Fetch subset columns from a Django API

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, api, django-rest-framework

I would like to get some columns of my Django API data. How can I do to get specific column without pulling all data as the does the following script ?

```
var data_from_api;
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/network/1/edges/')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => edges_from_api=data)
```

I just want to get `lanes`, `length` and `speed`.

Subset of my api data

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "edge_id": 1,
        "name": "Out 1 - E",
        "length": 4.0,
        "speed": 50.0,
        "lanes": 1,
        "param1": 3000.0,
        "param2": null,
        "param3": null,
        "road_type": 2,
        "source": 1,
        "target": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "edge_id": 2,
        "name": "Out 1 - NE",
        "length": 4.0,
        "speed": 50.0,
        "lanes": 1,
        "param1": 3000.0,
        "param2": null,
        "param3": null,
        "road_type": 2,
        "source": 1,
        "target": 3
    },
```

Comment: You'll need some support for that on the API's end. We don't know what kind of flexibility you get with that API, what Framework or even language the API is using... We can't guess what the request should look like, to accomplish what you are after, given no details on the backend.

Comment: I am using Django/python for that api

Comment: As @Narxx already said you have to change it inside the api, not in the frontend. if you cannot exclude properties with your api, you can filter them in frontend via : edges_from_api.map(data => ({ lanes: data.lanes, length: data.length, speed: data.speed}));

Comment: Ok, I will change it from backend side

Comment: Mention you are using Django in the question's title and description and tags. That will help bringing Python / Django helpers to this post.

Comment: I have a last question. How can I handle the integer inside my url  ?
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/network/1/edges/' Here it's one because I am in network 1. But a user can be in the network 2 and it should be 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/network/2/edges/'